# Docker: Keep Ubuntu container running after starting?

Tags: docker, containers, ubuntu-14.04, docker-image

I am trying to start a `docker container` using the `ubuntu` image:

```
docker container run -d --name ubuntu_assignment_4 6e4f1fe62
```

However as soon as I start the container it stops again.

Why does this happen and how can I ensure the container stays running?

The image I am trying to run here is: `ubuntu:14.04`

Comment: Need to see your Dockerfile, but likely your entry point is returning. Docker containers only run for as long as the entrypoint task is active. Once that task finishes and returns, the container halts.

Comment: In this case the image that I am trying to run is: ubuntu:14.04 , I will edit question to make that clear

Comment: There must be a Dockerfile that specifies a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`  directive.

Comment: What is your objective in running the ubuntu container?

Comment: @franklinsijo I want to then do a "container exec" to get a bash shell inside it and check what version of curl is installed on the container

Comment: You will exec only on a running container. Since there is nothing to keep it running, you can run the container on demand interactively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to use the `ubuntu:14.04` image without any modifications to it, you would not require a separate `Dockerfile`. And it is not possible to keep the plain `ubuntu:14.04` image running as a container.

You can directly launch the container with an interactive shell using the `ubuntu:14.04` image.

```
docker run -it ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

But the plain `ubuntu:14.04` image does not have `curl` pre-installed on it.

You will need a custom `Dockerfile` for this.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say exactly what is happening without seeing the complete Dockerfile that was used to build the image, but I am pretty certain that the trouble you are having is just because whatever task that is being started inside the container is finishing and exiting.

Docker containers work by having some command assigned (using `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` directives in the Dockerfile, or as an argument to `docker start` or `docker run` on the command line) which is the program that is started when the container loads. The container will live for as long as that task continues to run, and once that program finishes the container will terminate.

To specify the startup entrypoint at the command line, try:

```
docker create -it [image] /bin/bash
```

Then start it like this:

```
 docker start -ia [Container ID]
```

The container will exit once the shell exits, because this is assigning the shell as the entry point.

`cURL` may not be installed by default. It is possible to install it using `apt-get`. But again, once the shell is closed, the container will stop and any changes will be lost. As a start, try creating a new directory somewhere, and then add a file called `Dockerfile` with this content:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

That will create a new image with curl installed. then, from inside the new directory where the Dockerfile was created, use:

```
docker build .
docker images
```

which will build a new image, using the Dockerfile as the blueprint.
Once the build finishes, find the image ID for the new container, and run it using:

```
docker run -it [image id]
```

Ultimately, to make Docker really useful, the typical approach is to replace that last line in the Dockerfile (`ENTRYPOINT ["command"]`) with something that will continue running forever (like `ENTRYPOINT ["apache2"]` or `ENTRYPOINT ["redis"]` or similar). If you have experience using regular desktop/server OS installs, and full virtual machines like VMWare or VirtualBox, just remember that Docker is very different; the way it works and the patterns used to deploy it are not the same.

Comment: Thanks, for reference the docker file in this case will be the ubuntu:14.04 docker file as that is the image that I have pulled that corresponds to: 6e4f1fe62 in my command

Comment: `ubuntu:14.04 ` is not a Dockerfile, it is an image. Just running this image by itself will not do much. You need to read about Dockerfiles, what they are and how they are used to create new images (beecause to make docker do anything useful, you need to use your own Dockerfile to build a new image, and you can use `ubuntu:14.04 ` as the starting point).